# Configuring Texmaker to run mpost for FeynMP Graphics

Tags: texmaker, feynmf

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`feynmp-auto`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmp-auto)

What is the command line to be placed in the User

**Quick Build Command** of Texmaker to get:

LaTeX + **mpost** + dvips + ps2pdf + ViewPDF

That's to say, in order to avoid manually running `mpost` run on `file.mp` every time I run LaTeX command,  is there anyway TeXMaker will do it for me?

I used TexMaker's own Wizard, which produced following command line:

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|mpost --interaction nonstopmode |dvips -o %.ps %.dvi|ps2pdf %.ps|"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf
```

It looks fine, but when I run a `file.tex` file it takes indefinite time with no result.

Comment: Hello, anyone to help?

Comment: I thought I will get an answer quickly.

Comment: Would you please add a simple example of a file you want to process?

Answer (score 6):

With an updated TeX Live 2012 there's no need to call `mpost` from the command line, since this program is allowed to be called during the LaTeX run. Just modify the definition of `\endfmffile` to do the Metapost run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\makeatletter
\def\endfmffile{%
  \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
          end.^^J%
          endinput;}%
  \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
  \fi
  \IfFileExists{\thefmffile.mp}{\immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}}{}
  \let\thefmffile\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{abc}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25) 
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2} 
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2} 
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{4} 
\end{fmfgraph} 
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

This will produce `abc.1` that will be included on the next run, with the usual command line call.

With MiKTeX it might not work, depending if `mpost` is allowed in the "restricted shell".

Comment: I don't know why the package link in question, http://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmp-auto does not work above

Comment: @texenthusiast Well, wait until it's activated; I just uploaded it, but knowing myself, I'd forget this annotation if not made immediately. ;-)

Comment: sorry i thought it was old question and mistook it.  thanks