# How to automate mpost for FeynMP Graphics via Texmaker + Miktex on Windows 8

Tags: texmaker, feynmf

Producing FeynMF graphs requires manual running of `mpost` command on `.mp` file at terminal each time after [latex] compiling the `tex` document. In other words it goes like this:

`Latex + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF`

`mpost abc.mp`

`Latex + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF`

As you can see it takes three steps to just compile a single LaTeX file. Is there a way to configure TeXmaker in order to run entire command with single stroke? How to automate this process?

I am using latest edition of MiKTeX [not TeXLive 2012] on Win 8.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{fmffile}{abc}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,50)
            \fmfset{curly_len}{1.5mm}                       
            \fmfset{arrow_ang}{12}                          
            \fmfset{wiggly_len}{4mm}
            \fmfset{wiggly_slope}{50}   
        \fmfleft{L}
        \fmfright{R}
        \fmftop{T}
        \fmfbottom{B}
        \fmflabel{$a_3$}{T}        
        \fmflabel{$a_2$}{L}
        \fmflabel{$a_4$}{R}
        \fmflabel{$a_1$}{B}
        \fmf{plain_arrow,width=2,tension=2}{L,v1}
        \fmf{plain_arrow,width=2,tension=2}{v3,R}
        \fmf{plain_arrow,width=2,tension=2}{T,v2}
        \fmf{plain_arrow,width=2,tension=2}{B,v4}
        \fmfdot{v1,v2,v3}       
        \fmf{plain_arrow,lab.side=left, lab=$b$}{v1,v2}
        \fmf{plain_arrow,lab.side=left, lab=$c$}{v2,v3}
        \fmf{plain_arrow,lab.side=right,lab=$d$}{v3,v4}
        \fmf{plain_arrow,lab.side=right,lab=$a$}{v4,v1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
      \end{fmffile}
      \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Can http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74244/configuring-texmaker-to-run-mpost-for-feynmp-graphics help you? If so, let us know and we can close the question as duplicate. Otherwise, please tell what are the problem in using that solution.

Comment: Did you ask the earlier question as well Laura?

Comment: Yes it was me who asked the same question back then. I forgot my credentials to login and thank for the answer. However, installing TeXLive 2012 didn't help me in this case; it successfully compiled egreg's examples, but not mine where I have labels etc. So I am looking for work around Texmaker + Miktex combination if possible. Thank you so much!

Comment: Another problem with TeXLive 2012 is that it take indefinite to compile large FeynMP files. Then it doesn't allow any blank spaecs.. whereas with MikTex none was issue except for the long sequential command line.

Comment: Can't we just add a batch command line like this somewhere and link a command to it?
@echo off
mpost.exe
pause

Comment: I think `MPost` command of texmaker doesn't function at all.

Comment: @Laura If you use the redefinitions I suggested when answering your old question, then just running `pdflatex` with the `--shell-escape` option enabled, you should be able to compile the Metapost file without any other problem.