# feynmf working but NOT feynmp (FIXED!)

Tags: metapost, feynmf

I'm using Mac Mountainl Lion, TexShop (everything worked before on Leopard).

This is the first time I use feynmp on Mountain Lion since I upgraded and it's not working. When I use feynmf it seems O.K. but everybody know feynmf produces ugly bitmaps.

So what I'm I doing wrong here?

EDIT (FIXED!!)

I followed user egreg's advice and installed MacTex2012 and everything seems to work now.

To summarize: (with abc.mp being the name of a specific Feynman diagram)

With the old MacTex 2009 I had to manually open the abc.mp file with TexShop and choose MetaPost before Typesetting...after this step the abc.1 file is created and you can go back to your original TeX-file to Typeset with LaTeX and your Feynman diagrams should appear.

Alternatively you download MacTeX 2012 and it will do everything for you automatically. This is what I did.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Did you see my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74906/4427? I tried adding the code from `\usepackage{ifpdf}` to `\makeatother` to your example and, after the second LaTeX run, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I'll read up on your post and check, and post a feedback in a moment.

Comment: Hi again! I went to your link and copy-pasted your code and it didn't work. I think I need to install TeXLive2012, I have TeXLive 2009 maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Yes, that surely is a problem. Just download [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex), double click on it, do the install and launch TeX Live Utility. You'll need some time, but the result is worthy of it.

Comment: Please, let us know whether the update solves the issue.

Comment: Absolutely, I will post feedback here for future users.

Comment: Compile another time; at the first run the Metapost file is processed to produce an MPS file which can be read at the next run. It's perfectly normal that no `.mf` or `.tfm` file is produced with `feynmp`: you get the `abc.mp` file which is processed (automatically) with `mpost` to give `abc.1`.

Comment: It's the same not matter how many times I compile, don't know why really.

Comment: Please remove all `abc.*` files and typeset twice. For each run, add to your question the console output produced by TeXShop.

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to help you if you don't use the same file as the provided example, where there's *no* reference to `fgraphs`. I asked for *two* console outputs.

Comment: Sorry you're right my bad. But here's what I did in meantime: Since the console says I should process the abc.mp file with Metapost and then Typeset again, I somehow managed to locate Metapost and manually opened the abc.* file and Typeset it WITH Metapost. After this I typeset the original file with Latex and voila it worked. So the question now is; Why must I do all this manually? Something is wrong here.

Comment: It *can't* work automatically with TeX Live 2009, I thought it was clear from my comment. With 2009 you need to process the `.mp` file manually, as you found out.

Comment: Yes, but before (while on Leopard) I had no problem with this, that's why I was confused.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include the solution and editing the title to include "(FIXED!)", it would be better if you could post an answer to your own question and accept it (by clicking the tick mark after a day). That makes it easier to see that the question is solved and it will help others with the same problem to quickly find the solution.

Comment: I've just uploaded to CTAN the `feynmp-auto` package that will do the same as the added code (and something more); when it's available for TeX Live Utility to install, do it and change `\usepackage{feynmp}` to `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}`. No need to add fancy code any more.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort egreg, but I took your advice (installing MacTex2012) and now everything works fine. Thanks again. :)